# .Net core, Service Collection - class implements multiple generic interfaces

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

There is an interface that inherits another one

```
interface IA<T> {}
interface IB<T> : IA<T> {}
```

And a class that implements the IB

```
class C<T>: IB<T> {}
```

I used .NET core Service Collection to set up IoC. For example:

```
services.AddSingleton<IB<T>, C<T>>();
```

I am trying to find out a solution to auto-register IA to C and resole instance of IA, IB target to same an object of C.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

With MS.DI, you easily end up with the so-called [Torn Lifestyle](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/tornlifestyle.html) problem when you make the registration as follows:

```cs
// Bad idea: don't do this!
services.AddSingleton<C<X>>();
services.AddSingleton<IB<X>, C<X>>();
services.AddSingleton<IA<X>, C<X>>();
```

These three registrations lead to three individual registrations for `C<X>`, which leads to three separate instances. This problem is called a Torn Lifestyle.

Instead, you rather be able to always resolve the same single instance of `C<X>` independently whether you request it through its `IA<X>` or `IB<X>` interface, or whether you request it directly through the concrete type of `C<X>`.

The way to achieve this with MS.DI is letting two registrations redirect the resolve to a third registration. For instance:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<C<X>>();
services.AddSingleton<IA<X>>(
    c => c.GetRequiredService<C<X>>());
services.AddSingleton<IB<X>>(
    c => c.GetRequiredService<C<X>>());
```

This solution, unfortunately, has its limitations, especially when it comes to working with generic types.  As your `C<T>` is a generic type, you might want to be able to substitute `T` for any suitable type, without having to make all registrations for all those types explicitly.

MS.DI allows this scenario by making a registration such as the following:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IA<>), typeof(C<>));
```

This registration allows any arbitrary closed version of `C<T>` to be resolved when any arbitrary closed version of `IA<T>` is requested. In other words, when requesting an `IA<Person>`, you'll get the single instance for `C<Person>`. This is a form of Auto-Registration, which allows many types to be resolved with a single registration.

But now the trouble starts, because with MS.DI, it is impossible to integrate the first approach that prevented the Torn Lifestyle issue with the latter Auto-Registration approach. That's because, with MS.DI, the only way to prevent the Torn Lifestyle issue is by making a registration that uses a delegate. But there's no `AddSingleton(Type, Func<IServiceProvider, Object>)` overload that would enable this, and to my knownledge it isn't possible to build such functionality on top of MS.DI.

This means that there is no suitable solution with MS.DI when it comes to preventing Torn Lifestyles for open-generic registrations. There are two workarounds I can think of: either you make all closed-registrations manually, or you hide the use of `C<T>` and its interfaces behind a proxy or facade. How that would look, however, is highly dependent on your design, so it's impossible to be more specific about that.